# Limpar o console a cada 30s

Tags: c#

Como faço para limpar o console a cada 30s sempre?
Tentei criar com timer mas não funcionou, ou eu devo ter feito errado.
Segue o código:

```
    var time = new Timer(LimparConsole,null,0,30000);

public static void LimparConsole (object sender){

Console.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Qual `timer` é esse? Outra coisa, geralmente, timer tem que ser disparado, talvez esteja faltando um `timer.Start()`

Comment: Threading, não contém timer.start ;/

Comment: Algum motivo pra ser da lib de Threading? Não poderia ser o próprio [Timer do System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Eu uso alguns thread.sleep na classe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o console roda no método Main, que por sua vez, é um método estático, acredito que a saída é usar outra Thread.

No código abaixo, crio uma Thread "t" que vai aguardar 10 segundos, e então limpa o console.

Depois da criação da Thread, segue o processamento normal do sistema.

```
class Program
{
    static int loop = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        bool aplicacaoRodando = true;

       Thread t = new Thread(()=>{

           while (aplicacaoRodando)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(10000);
               Console.Clear();
               loop = 0;
           }

        });

       t.Start();

       while (aplicacaoRodando)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
           loop++;
           Console.WriteLine("Tá rodando a aplicação..." + loop);
       }

    }
}
```

ps. Coloquei o intervalo de 10.000 ms apenas para exemplificar e tornar o teste mais rápido. Basta alterar o `Thread.Sleep(10000);` para o intervalo desejado.

Comment: Teria como eu continuar mexendo no console?

Comment: depois do `t.Start()` pode fazer o processo normal da sua aplicação... o que está abaixo dele é apenas didático para representar a aplicação rodando